# htaccess redirect specific page of specific domains to specific pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have created a new Wordpress site that will replace a multi-domain website.
Server redirections has been done on different domains to point all of them to the same path.

**I need do redirect pages based on the parent domain and also, redirect specific domain pages to new specific domain pages .**

For example, when "www.mysite-example.com.au/contact" is requested it should redirect to "mysite.com.au/contact-us" and also "www.mysite-example.com.au/contact/form" should redirect to "mysite-example.com.au/request-contact-form"

Here is my current htaccess where I'm doing global redirection

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abilitypeople.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://abilitypeople.co.uk/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abilitypeople.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://abilitypeople.co.uk/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abilitypeople.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://abilitypeople.com.au/ [R=301,L]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Does any one know how to create these redirections **on the same htacces**

```
"www.mysite-example.com.au/contact" -> "mysite.com.au/contact-us"
"www.mysite-example.com.au/contact/form" -> "mysite-example.com.au/request-contact-form"

"www.mysite-example.co.uk/contact" -> "mysite.co.uk/contact-us"
"www.mysite-example.co.uk/contact/form" -> "mysite-example.co.uk/request-contact-form"
```

By the way, thanks to anubhava for his help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your rules like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abilitypeople\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://abilitypeople.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(abilitypeople\.(?:co\.uk|com\.au))$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^contact/?$ contact.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. the extension is quit different and also I would like to remove the "www" on the redirection. Does this will make it?
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www\.(mysite-example\.(?:com\.au|co\.uk))$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ contact.php [L,QSA]

Comment: I will try it today around 5pm (in 7 hours).
By the way, one off my domain has .com.au and the other .co.uk, can you explain quickly why this: www\.(mysite-example.com\.(?:au|uk) can work? (I'm a bit perplex) 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for your fast responses, will try it this evening

Comment: Hey Anubhava, I had a test, however all RewriteRules aren't working.
I update my question to let you know tests completed. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Hmm that is only possible if there is any other rule for `/clients/` OR else `/clients/` also has a .htaccess? Make sure `301` rules are very first rules.

Comment: I'm using wordpress, you are right, I have another global redirection in the htaccess. Check my update

Comment: Ah you didn't mention about WP before. Make sure you have home and site url in WP permalink settings **without www** also.

Comment: Inside my WP permalink settings, I manage to modify the home/site url according to the domain. So, for mysite-example.co.uk I have http://mysite-example.co.uk and for mysite-example.com.au I have http://mysite-example.com.au. However, redirections aren't still working. Only the first rewrite rule is taken. Any idea? otherwise, I will make global redirection

Comment: Rule is indeed doing global redirection. Make sure there is no `/client/.htaccess` and you test in a new browser.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.
I removed their previous project (no other htacces)
Cleared my cash/tried other browsers, still the same issue.
I make simple global redirect, but I would like to map specific pages... (reading content without any luck) 

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.XXXX.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://XXXX.co.uk/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.XXXX.co.uk$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://XXXX.co.uk/ [R=301,L]
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.XXXX.com.au$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://XXXX.com.au/ [R=301,L]

Comment: There is no way anyone can understand code written in comments. Please edit your question and post comment there.